# Guideline in ConstrainLayout XML my layout dose not look right can anyone help me fix it

Tags: android, xml

Hi as you can see in the image that i have two Teams and i want them side by side
but when i did it thru the Design section in Android studio it came out sloppy they don't look centered and i want also that the buttons should be all the same size.

thanks
Joe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7klY7.png)

[this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKBJS.png)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:id="@+id/TeamA"
        android:paddingTop="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.202" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/n0"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TeamA"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.215" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+3 POINTS"
        android:id="@+id/points3"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n0"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.127" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+2 POINTS"
        android:id="@+id/points2"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.124" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FREE THROW"
        android:id="@+id/freeThrow"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="freeThrow"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.101" />










    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Team B"
        android:id="@+id/TeamB"
        android:paddingTop="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.773"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/n0B"
        android:padding="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TeamB"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.761" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+3 POINTS"
        android:id="@+id/points3B"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/n0B"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.827" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+2 POINTS"
        android:id="@+id/points2B"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points2B"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points3B"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.81" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="FREE THROW"
        android:id="@+id/freeThrowB"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="freeThrow"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/points2B"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.854" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="192dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TableLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TeamA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="36sp"
        android:text="Team A"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/TeamB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="36sp"
        android:text="Team B"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/n0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="0"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/n0B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="0"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points3"
        android:text="+3 POINTS"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points3B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points3"
        android:text="+3 POINTS"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points2"
        android:text="+2 POINTS"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/points2B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="points2B"
        android:text="+2 POINTS"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/freeThrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="freeThrow"
        android:text="FREE THROW"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/freeThrowB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:onClick="freeThrow"
        android:text="FREE THROW"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This should give you your desired result. Keep in mind that the `TableRows` where the `TextViews` are the children the gravity of the text has also be set to center (`android:gravity="center"`)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help what should be the closing bracket, also i want more space between the two columns,

Comment: Closing is </TableLayout> and more space between could probably be achieved by setting a layout_margin for the child views of a TableRow.